# Load Balancers methodology (L4, L7) and AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb

Recently I have been trying to catch up with the knowledge that I'm missing around Load Balancing internals and I have found this great [article](https://blog.envoyproxy.io/introduction-to-modern-network-load-balancing-and-proxying-a57f6ff80236)

But it made me think about more questions than before;)

Till now I understood that if we talk about L4 LB we can differentiate:

- LB terminate type - that creates for each incoming connection, a new one to backend.
- LB passthrough type - that might be split into NAT, or Direct routing one (eventually with tunneling)

1. Now one of my questions that came to my mind is that how does it fit into AWS world - what type of LB is AWS Network Load Balancer in that case?

The next thing is about L7 LB's.

2. Does layer 7 LB also relies on NAT, or Direct routing? Or it's completely beyond that? When it's quite a lot of materials around layer 4, typically layer 7 is really poor in terms of proper articles covering internals - I know only top products like: haproxy or nginx, but still don't get the difference between them :(

I will be very thankful for anyone who might provide me with at least some piece of advice how connect the dots there :)

Answer (score 0):

> what type of LB is AWS Network Load Balancer in that case?

Network Load Balancer is a layer 4 load balancing, check the information provided on the amazon docs:

> A Network Load Balancer functions at the **fourth layer of the Open Systems Interconnection (OSI) model**. It can handle millions of requests per second. After the load balancer receives a connection request, it selects a target from the target group for the default rule. It attempts to open a TCP connection to the selected target on the port specified in the listener configuration.
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html

For the second question.

> Does layer 7 LB also relies on NAT, or Direct routing? Or it's completely beyond that?

In the amazon world application load balancer is the only wich support layer 7 LB and works like mention in the article

> "The client makes a single HTTP/2 TCP connection to the load balancer. The load balancer then proceeds to make two backend connections"

So for the client is direct connection with the load balancer, and that connection is splited to be served at backend pools.

Comment: Sorry for maybe not clearly stated question - I knew that NLB is layer 4 - but still I'm quite curious how exactly NLB in AWS send traffic - if it's terminated and re-established or it's passthrough (so connection is modified on the fly to adopt destination IP and source IP - NAT)